# Comprbar input con 2 selectores

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

necesito de su ayuda. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 $("input[numero='"+$("#jugada").val()+"']").each(function() {
    var monto = $(this).attr("monto");
    jugado = parseInt(jugado) + parseInt(monto);
  })
```

Quiero saber como hacer para que en:

```
$("input[numero='"+$("#jugada").val()+"']").each
```

Puedo hacr la comprobacion por 2 atributos, el atributo numero y otro atributo al mismo tiempo.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Carlos, recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un selector por tanto atributos quieras como por ejemplo:

```
input[atributo1='valor'][atributo2='valor']
```

Un ejemplo funcional:

```js
$("input[numero='1'][monto='3000']").each(function() {
  var monto = $(this).attr("monto");
  console.log(monto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input numero="1" monto="1000" type="text">
<input numero="2" monto="2000" type="text">
<input numero="1" monto="3000" type="text">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si miras en la documentacion de [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) verás que en la sección de Multiple-Attribute Selector (selector con atributos multiples) la sintaxis es concatenando los `[ ]`:

Siguiendo tu ejemplo:

```
$("input[numero='"+$("#jugada").val()+"'][name='prueba']").each
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo mio

Comment: @CarlosMaldonado nada. Recuerda leer/investigar un poco más la proxima vez :P